# AWS invalid principal in bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, policy

I am writing a cfn template for S3 bucket. I have defined the principal in bucket policy as

```
 Principal:
    AWS:
      Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
        - !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
        - ":root"
```

I want to make principal as the aws Account. This is giving me an invalid principal error.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [Fn::Join](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) you need two levels of `-`, and also it should be `iam`:

```
 Principal:
    AWS:
      Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - 'arn:aws:iam::'
          - !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
          - ":root"
```

But it would be easier to use [Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSClouadFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html):

```
 Principal:
    AWS: !Sub 'arn:aws::${AWS::AccountId}:root"
```

Answer (score 0):

The ARN for an IAM root principal looks like `arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root`.

Note: `iam`, not `s3` and two colons before the account number, not 3.